# Decomposition of an IP header

Tags: c, network-programming, ip, pcap

I have to do a sniffer as an assignment for the security course. I am using C and the pcap library. I got everything working well (since I got a code from the internet and changed it). But I have some questions about the code.

```
u_int ip_len = (ih->ver_ihl & 0xf) * 4;
```

`ih` is of type `ip_header`, and its currently pointing the to IP header in the packet.
`ver_ihl` gives the version of the IP.
I can't figure out what is: `& 0xf) * 4;`

Comment: +1 for being honest and thorough :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

& is the bitwise and operator, in this case you're anding ver_ihl with 0xf which has the effect of clearing all the bits other than the least signifcant 4

0xff & 0x0f = 0x0f

ver_ihl is defined as first 4 bits = version + second 4 = Internet header length. The and operation removes the version data leaving the length data by itself. The length is recorded as count of 32 bit words so the *4 turns ip_len into the count of bytes in the header

In response to your comment:

bitwise and ands the corresponding bits in the operands. When you and anything with 0 it becomes 0 and anything with 1 stays the same.

0xf = 0x0f = binary 0000 1111

So when you and 0x0f with anything the first 4 bits are set to 0 (as you are anding them against 0) and the last 4 bits remain as in the other operand (as you are anding them against 1). This is a common technique called bit masking.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND

Comment: i got the idea (ver_ihl contains the Version (4 bits) + Internet header length (4 bits)) but i still didn't get how this operation is removing the version data. when you are anding with 0xf does this mean that your anding only the fist 4 bits?

Answer (score 1):

Reading from [RFC 791](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc791.html#ixzz0iNOAO9Kd) that defines IPv4:

> A summary of the contents of the internet header follows:
>
> ```
>  0                   1                   2                   3   
>  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |Version|  IHL  |Type of Service|          Total Length         |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> ```

The first 8 bits of the IP header are a combination of the version, and the IHL field.

> IHL:  4 bits
>
> Internet Header Length is the length of the internet header in 32
>     bit words, and thus points to the beginning of the data.  Note that
>     the minimum value for a correct header is 5.

What the code you have is doing, is taking the first 8 bits there, and chopping out the IHL portion, then converting it to the number of bytes.  The bitwise AND by `0xF` will isolate the IHL field, and the multiply by 4 is there because there are 4 bytes in a 32-bit word.

Answer (score 0):

The ver_ihl field contains two 4-bit integers, packed as the low and high nybble. The length is specified as a number of 32-bit words. So, if you have a Version 4 IP frame, with 20 bytes of header, you'd have a ver_ihl field value of 69. Then you'd have this:

```
  01000101
& 00001111
  --------
  00000101
```

So, yes, the "&0xf" masks out the low 4 bits.